# Testing mongoose queries in jest - just the first test block performs the query

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jestjs

```js
//first test suite

test('queries first time', async (done) => {
  mockingoose(Model).toReturn({ name: 'asd' });
  const doc = await Model.find({})
  console.log(doc); //right value
  mockingoose.resetAll();
  done();
})
test('queries second time', async (done) => {
  mockingoose(Model).toReturn({ name: 'asd' });
  const doc = await Model.find({})
  console.log(doc); //undefined
  mockingoose.resetAll();
  done();
})

//second test suite without mocking the data

test('queries first time', (done) => {
  Model.find({}, (err, doc) => {
    console.log(err, doc); //logs values
    return
  });
  done();
})

test('queries second time', (done) => {
  Model.find({}, (err, doc) => {
    console.log(err, doc); //doesn't log
    return
  });
  done();
})
```

So the issue is that while testing mongoose with jest, just the first test block's query runs. The mocking is to actually have some result of querying on the model, but with or without it, the second block of test never works. It doesn't even throw an error, it just always returns undefined, or as in the second test suite, the callback function doesn't get called.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's my understading that if you want to define a test suite, you should use `describe` and `it`. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb

Comment: Didn't solve the problem :/